# Gibt es Akzente/Dialekte, bei denen das R immer ausgesprochen wird?

Tags: pronunciation, letter

Ein Beispieltext:

> Gott ist eine faustgrobe Antwo**r**t, eine Undelicatesse gegen uns Denke**r** –, im Grunde soga**r** bloss ein faustgrobes Verbot an uns: Ih**r** sollt nicht denken! (Friedrich Nietzsche)

Die fettgedruckten *R* werden im Hochdeutschen nicht mehr ausgesprochen, aber es ist mir bekannt, dass sie die Aussprache beeinflussen. Jetzt ist meine Frage, ob es Akzente/Dialekte gibt, bei denen das *R* in allen Positionen ähnlich wie am Anfang eines Wortes ausgesprochen wird.

Comment: Ich denke, der Fachbegriff, unter dem man etwas zu der Frage finden könnte, lautet *rhotischer Dialekt*.

Comment: Ich glaube, man kann die Frage wie folgt verkürzen: »Gibt es einen deutschen Dialekt, in dem die Pronomen *wir* und *ihr* mit einem R (egal ob [r], [ʀ] oder [ʁ]) ausgesprochen werden?« - Ich glaube, die Antwort ist »nein«, aber ich kenne bei weitem nicht alle deutschen Dialekt. Am ehesten würde ich das noch bei den alemannischen Dialekten erwarten.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Gerade "wir" ist ein Wort, das in tausend verschieden Formen ausgesprochen wird. Wiktionary listet: [viːɐ̯], [viː], [vɐ], [vɔr], [vər], [mɪr], [mər], [mɔr], [mɐ]. Ich persönlich variiere die Aussprache sogar, je nachdem ob ich mehr ins Platt verfalle oder nicht, oder auch je nach Wort, was danach folgt. Und somit spreche ich es mal mit R, mal nicht.

Comment: Hitlerparodiedeutsch

Comment: Ich bin auch der Überzeugung dass extrem häufig auftretende Wörter Sonderfälle darstellen.  Die Beispiele in der Frage sind besser.  Weitere Schibbolethe wären ins Deutsche übernommene Fremdwörter (*Dinar*, *Server*, *Quicksort*, *Deir_ez-Zor* ...).

Comment: Auch die bearbeitete Fassung geht noch davon aus, daß etwa in _Antwort_ kein _r_ gesprochen würde. Wird es aber natürlich, denn in diesem Fall ist [ɐ̯] das _r_.

Comment: Wobei @chirlu's [ɐ̯] auch mit vielen anderen Lauten realisiert werden kann.

Comment: @Crissov: oder Rrrrrammsteindeutsch

Comment: @Donny: Hier auf Stackexchange gehören die Posts nicht dir sondern der Gemeinschaft, deswegen sind Korrekturen zur sprachlichen Verbesserung erwünscht und das zurückeditierten zu umgangssprachlichen Formen wie *nimmer* nicht erwünscht. Deswegen habe ich deinen Edit zurückgesetzt.

Comment: _Nimmer_ ist auch mehrdeutig, weil es einerseits _nicht mehr_, andererseits _niemals_ bedeuten kann. (cc @Jan)

Comment: Ich habe verstanden.

Answer (score 3):

Es trifft nicht zu, dass die genannten *r* «im Hochdeutschen nicht mehr ausgesprochen» (vokalisiert) werden. Es kommt darauf an, welches Hochdeutsch du meinst. Im Schweizer Hochdeutsch werden solche *r* nämlich durchaus als *r* ausgesprochen – mehrheitlich als [r], in der Ostschweiz und in Basel auch als [ʀ] oder [ʁ].

Im Hochdeutschen verhält es sich ganz ähnlich wie im Englischen. Auch da hängt es von der jeweiligen Varietät ab, ob das *r* am Silbenende vokalisiert oder als *r* ausgesprochen wird. Die Vokalisierung ist etwa in der britischen *Received Pronunciation* verbreitet, während in den USA die Aussprache als *r* üblich ist.

Comment: Die Schweizer Sprecher in der [Österreichischen Aussprachedatenbank](http://www.adaba.at/) sprechen auch viele *r* aus dem Beispielsatz vokalisch, insbesondere _ihr_, _sogar_, _Verbot_; _Denker_ ist nicht in der Datenbank enthalten, aber andere entsprechende Bildungen (z.B. _Richter_) werden mit [ɐ] gesprochen. Ein konsonantisches _r_ war nur in _Antwort_ zu besichtigen.

Comment: Tatsächlich – allerdings klingen die angeblich schweizerischen Sprecherinnen und Sprecher in dieser Datenbank für meine Ohren oft nicht besonders schweizerisch, sondern eher preussisch. Woher haben sie denn die Stimmen genommen? Wenn man Radiobeiträge auf srf.ch sich anhört, so sind die Stimmen oft viel schweizerischer – besonders dann, wenn es sich nicht um berufliche Sprecherinnen oder Sprecher handelt.

Comment: Die Schweizer Sprecher sind Monique Furrer und Guido Schaller, Radiosprecher. Leider habe ich keinen Lebenslauf o.ä. mit näheren Angaben zu ihrer Herkunft gefunden.

Answer (score 1):

In der Oberlausitzer Mundart werden die fettgedruckten Rs gesprochen und sogar hervorgehoben (wie jedes andere R auch).

Answer (score 0):

So weit ich weiß war die Aussprache mit [r] früher standard.  Die Frage könnte auch so formuliert sein: "Gibt es *noch* solche Akzente oder wann gab es zuletzt solche Akzente (unter Muttersprachlern)?"

Ich kenne nicht alle Dialekte oder alle deutsche Akzente, kann aber schon sagen, dass **viele Dialektsprecher [r] immer aussprechen, wenn sie Standarddeutsch sprechen**. Also haben sie einen **Akzent** mit [r] auf Standarddeutsch.

Zum Beispiel bei den Donauschwaben - deren Dialekte nicht von so weit südlich stammen, aber vielleicht etwas konservative Merkmale erhalten haben - ist es oft so.  (Bei ihnen lauten übrigens *wir* und *ihr* auch auf Dialekt schlicht [mir] und [ir], mit [r], aber in anderen Fällen fällt das [r] weg.)

(Selbstverständlich gibt es auch viele Muttersprachler ganz anderer Sprachen die auf Deutsch tendenziell [r] immer aussprechen.)

Da spezifische und insbesondere häufige Wörter sich ändern (*da* war mal *dar*) sind Fremdwörter mE die besseren Schibbolethe, zB: *Server*, *Dinar*, *Temesvar*, *Quicksort*, *Deir ez-Zor* usw.

Answer (score -1):

Zumindest im Bairischen Sprachraum (Bayern + Österreich - Vorarlberg) wird das *R* in der Standardsprache immer ausgesprochen, sowie auch in der Umgangssprache wenn es nicht durch Dialektelemente bedungen wird.

Im Dialekt kann es schon passieren, dass Wörter ersetzt werden (zB ihr = es) oder sich durch den Dialekt in der Aussprache verändern (zB eure = eichane).

Über die anderen Sprachräume des Deutschen kann ich keine Aussage treffen, wobei Deutsch sicher "R-freundlich" ist.

Comment: *Mia san mia*. -1.

Comment: Falsch! Ich wurde 1965 in Graz geboren, habe bis 1997 in der Steiermark gelebt, und lebe seitdem in Wien: Ich habe noch nie einen Österreicher (auch keinen Nachrichtensprecher) das Wort »ihr« mit einem R aussprechen gehört. Weder im Dialekt noch in der Hochsprache. Besonders wenn der Buchstabe r den Endlaut eines Wortes verursacht, wird es fast immer als [ɐ] ausgesprochen. Auch im Hochdeutschen, und auch in Österreich. In »wer«, »der«, »Hammer«, »Fenster« usw. habe ich weder bei einem Dialekt-Sprecher, noch bei einem ausgebildeten Berufs-Sprecher je ein [r], [ʀ] oder [ʁ] gehört.