# Any difference in the pronounciation of "er", "eh", "ehe" and "eher"?

Tags: pronunciation

I know that these little useful words *er*, *eh*, *ehe* and *eher* have different meanings and usage. The problem is that when I try to pronounce them, they sound very, very similar. Especially inside a sentence and not as single, clearly pronounced words (which I can find in any online dictionary).

I wonder if natives, in everyday speaking, pronounce them in the same way or not. In this case is the pronunciation important in order to get the right meaning or is it just a matter of context and position of the word?

I'm asking because I'm interested in achieving a good German accent and since I didn't know about their existence, I haven't clearly heard these words pronounced by natives yet (except for *er*).

---

---

[edit: added *er* as suggested in the comments]

Comment: Another word to consider is _er_, which is quite close in pronunciation to _eher_. But no two of these words are pronounced the same.

Comment: How about "**air**", " y**ay**"", "y**ay** **uh**", and "**A air**"?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Is that German?

Comment: No, English, my attempt at finding words that resembled the sounds in OP's question

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I see. That's a good idea. But I'm afraid that's maybe impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The four are actually pretty discernable once you know what you need to do. We have two variants that end in *er* and we have two that don’t. And we also have three variants that have an additional *eh* in the beginning and one that doesn’t. We can consider the cases independently:

- *eh* at the beginning means that a long [e:] is added.
- *er* at the end is pronounced with a vocalic *r*<sup>†</sup>
- *e* at the end is reduced to a shwa [ə].

Which leaves us with plain *er.* That one *should* just be a vocalic *r* but the *e* preceding it is pronounced in some way. It can be rendered more or less as any of the short /e/ sounds ([e] or [ɛ]).

Putting it all together we have:

- /e:/
- /e:ə/
- /e:ɐ/
- /eɐ/ or /ɛɐ/ or /ɛ/ or some variant of it.

Only *er* is an odd one out, but ‘you’ll know when you need to hear it’.

---

†: [This question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/26316/15318) exists, basically saying that *r* remain unpronounced in German. However, *er* is *always* distinguishable from plain *e* in some way, be it that one is reduced to the e-shwa and the other to the a-shwa.

Answer (score 7):

The prerequisite for this answer is knowing how to pronounce *er* and *sehen* (which you might hear in the very first lesson of a German course). The IPA signs for the words you asked for are:

> - for *eh*, [eː] long *e* as the [eː] in *s**e**hen*
> - for *ehe* (or *Ehe*, which is not the same), [ˈeːə]. I.e. the same long *e*  as above and then the second *e* of *seh**e**n*.
> - for *eher*, [ˈeːɐ], the sound concatenation of the words *eh* and *er*, but stress in the first.
> - for *er*, [eːɐ]. Well, my percepcion is just that *eher*'s first vowel is longer.

Comment: I thought [ˈeːʰə] was an accepted variant for _Ehe_ - but OK, the question was about _ehe_

Comment: Still difficult for me to pronounce them in a clear different way, but definitely useful. Now I understand better the difference. Can you add also "er" (see latest edit) ?

Comment: @WalterTross I meant *Ehe* is meaningwise not the same as *ehe* (which is clear for advanced basic-levels, but basic-basic levels are those who might read this answer [not saying the OP is one of them]).

Answer (score 4):

I have thought about how I can answer you without speaking, so I have searched for a few videos in which you can find your answer.

Ehe (1:35 Min):
https://youtu.be/1p2cTwcqt_M

Eh:
Like "Ehe", without the last syllable.

Eher (1:30)
https://youtu.be/JcmDlftUzck

Comment: Welcome to german.stackexchange. As a new user, you are probably unaware of the fact that we tend to avoid "link-only-answers". That is, the links you provided are likely to be unreachable in the future and makes your answer pretty much, well, meaningless. That being said, I agree that questions about pronunciation always require some kind of verbal response. That makes it hard to answer such a question, but luckily there's a phonetic alphabet (IPA) that can be used to describe pronunciation.